# How do i apply this code to multiple cells?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a code that lets me modify a specific cell's information from other cells as long as it's selected, but i needed to be able to select multiple cells.

i've tried multiplying the below code but with h4,h5,h6,etc instead of h3 and doesn't work. it instead completely disables the code, even the already functioning part and i have to restart excel.

```
With Selection


If Selection.Value = Range("h3") Then
   Range("bk3").Value = True
   Range("l3").Value = Now
   If MsgBox("Do you want to sign?", vbYesNo, "Signature Confirmation") = vbYes Then  '<---- Confirmation Pop-Up
    VarNUMCB = InputBox("Type Collab. Number") '<---- Collab. Number Pop-Up.
    Range("j3").Value = Range("j3").Value & " | " & VarNUMCB
   Else
   End If
Else
   Range("bk3").Value = False

End If

End with
```

note: i don't want the changes to be made on l3,j3 and bk3 from any selected cell. each cell should be linked to its own line(horizontal) and selecting multiple cells from the H column should properly fill the rest of the linked information.

Comment: You need to `Set CellsRange = Selection` and then loop through all the selected cells `For Each C in CellsRange` using the `Cells(C.Row, "YourColumn")`for example.

Comment: Have a look at `Intersect`

Comment: What is the context of this code? I would like to see the beginning and the end of the Sub. Is it called by pressing a hotkey, as a response to selecting cells, or called by another Sub?

Comment: @z32a7ul there are 2 subs(1 for each button). this is the second button.
context:
the first button automatically ticks the respective box if the number is positive. it will also register the date it was ticked and ask + register the collab's number to identify the responsible for the act in case it becomes necessary to know.
all of this must happen in dozens of cells and all this info is gathered horizontally.
this second button is used for when a negative number turns positive, but since it was negative before, the first button didnt register it, thats where the second one comes in.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer i was able to pull through, it may not be the most effective but it does its job.
(i have to apply this to each line, pretty painful if there are dozens/hundreds of lines

```
If cel.Value = Range("H3") 0 Then                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         'What's up? nice, you found me. yeah it was the intern. so many "if" statements for no reason? i like the extra work :D
    If Range("l3").Value = "" Then
       Range("bk3").Value = True
       Range("l3").Value = Now
       If MsgBox("Do you want to sign?", vbYesNo, "Signature Confirmation") = vbYes Then  '<---- Confirmation Pop-Up
          VarNUMCB = InputBox("Place Collab. Number") '<---- Collab. Numb.Pop-Up
       Else
       End If

          If Range("h3").Value <= 0 Then
             Range("j3").Value = Range("j3").Value & " | " & VarNUMCB
          Else
          End If

    Else
    End If

  Else
  End If
```